# Nginx : redirect to port based on domain prefix (dynamically)

Tags: nginx, node.js

I'm trying to use nginx to redirect to ports (running nodeJS apps) based on the domain prefix. So far, I can redirect

- example.com:80  --> port 8502
- 5555.example.com:80  --> port 5555
- 6666.example.com:80  --> port 6666

Is there a way to do this kind of redirection without having to copy-paste this over and over?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 5555.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://example.com:5555;
  }
}
```

I figured I should do this with regular expressions, so I tried the following, but without any success :

```
~^(?<theport>.+)\.example\.com$   #then changed proxy_pass to http://example.com:$theport

~^([0-9]+)\.example\.com$  #then changed proxy_pass to http://example.com:$1
```

Comment: You might be able to do it with a map and variables.

Comment: I'm new to nginx, could you elaborate a little please? :)

Comment: you could probably do this programmatically with [Varnish](http://varnish-cache.org) (which allows you to compile your own c++ modules in) or our product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) which allows you to alter requests with lua or jscript.  Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who make WinGate.

Comment: @BernardSaucier did you solved this issue? I'm get in the same trouble...

Comment: Take a look here https://serverfault.com/questions/920534/nginx-proxy-subdomains-to-other-addresses-and-ports

Comment: I did figure it out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808860/nginx-redirect-to-port-according-to-domain-prefix-dynamically/38810749#38810749