# nginx proxy subdomains to other addresses and ports

Tags: nginx, domain, reverse-proxy, subdomain

I'm newbie with nginx, but I need to create some proxy rules based on the subdomain to redirect to another IP and Port.

This is my case:

```
My domain.com has IP y.y.y.y and accepts requests on port 80
My subdomains are:
- admin.domain.com -> I need to proxy to x.x.x.x:3434
- user.domain.com -> I need to proxy tox.x.x.x:3435
- vendor.domain.com -> I need to proxy to x.x.x.x:3436
```

All subdomains are mapped to the `y.y.y.y` but in nginx I need to proxy to `x.x.x.x:ZZZ` (ZZZ is the specific port of the other services).

I was trying this example but without success: https://rainbow-six3.com/plesknginx/

**Someone can provide an sample how to configure this on nginx?**

Comment: If that works, it should be an answer, not a question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3434;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name user.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3435;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name vendor.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3436;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: For nginx:  vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject && sudo systemctl restart nginx